# Javascript adding properties to objects - native VS underscore.js .extend method 

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been exploring backbone js recently and found the use of Model and others is like this:
`Backbone.Model.extend({ /* bla bla */ });`
And it's using underscore js's extend function to do that

I saw extend just used for adding properties to an object
So, what's the big deal if I use `myObj.extend({myProp: myPropValue});`
instead of `myObj.myProp = myPropValue;`

**UPDATE:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467305/1181782) as addition. I think it's cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both achieve the same result. However the `extend` method is more flexible because you can add multiple properties in a single call.

But `extend` is a function that originated in jQuery and is not native to Javascript, and has been implemented in underscore.js so the native method of `myObj.myProp = myPropValue;` will be more efficient, and is available without the aid of jQuery or underscore.js.

The difference in performance though is likely to be so negligible that using `extend` shouldn't be something to worry about.

Comment: I am talking about underscore extend not jquery's

Comment: Cool, if this answer is useful and/or you consider it to be correct, please remember to upvote and/or accept as answer. Thanks